# C++ - Make pointed-to object part of object constness

Tags: c++, constants, immutability, c++17, mutable

```
class SomeClass{

private:
    int* p;

public:
    SomeClass() {p = new int();}

    void foo() const {*p = 20;}

};

//...

const SomeClass obj;
obj.foo();
```

Let's say I consider the pointed-to object as part of the constness of the class. Do I have any way to make sure it's not modified in const functions (apart from not forgetting about it)? (No, I don't mean making it `const int*`)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const

Comment: highly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852717/what-can-a-const-method-change.  I'm trying to see if there is a duplicate.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: you an object that will work properly in a const function.  such as `string` for `char*` and `vector` for most other types.

Comment: The "duplicate" has no answer to this question at the moment. They ask about array-pointers and all answers suggest std::vector. It was 6+ years ago, I assume propagate_const didn't exist at that time.