# c++ const-ness of member functions for a C wrapper

Tags: c++, class, constants

i have an object that, at its most basic level, looks like this:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

class x_link {
    public:
        x_link()
        {
            display_ = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
        }

        ~x_link()
        {
            XCloseDisplay(display_);
        }

        Display* display_ptr() const
        {
            return display_;
        }

    private:
        Display* display_;
};
```

i was wondering how "const" `x_link::display_ptr()` should be in a case like this.

this older question, [Should member functions be “const” if they affect logical state, but not bitwise state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208184/should-member-functions-be-const-if-they-affect-logical-state-but-not-bitwise), gives me the impression that since my method doesn't (itself) impact either the logical or bitwise state of the object, `const` is the way to go.

but at the same time, providing the `Display*` allows users to break the object (for example, by calling `XCloseDisplay()` themselves), which would be a very non-const thing to do.

any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you provide access to the private pointer?

Comment: because life is short and Xlib is huge.  unless i provide an interface to all the parts of Xlib i care about within this object (which is possible, but it means a big, specialized object), other code will need access to that pointer.

Comment: This looks like a simple RAII style use. Any reason why you dont use `std::shared_ptr` (or `boost::shared_ptr`) with a custom deleter? It will help you get things like copy constructors and assignment working right.

Comment: Is it safe to call XCloseDispaly on the same pointer twice?  I ask because you have broken the rule of three here and you're likely to run into a double delete at some point.

Comment: @Ed S.:
it is not.  in the actual object, i have disabled the copy constructor and the assignment operator because that usage doesn't really 'make sense' in this context (to me).  i will revisit it if something changes.

Comment: @Michael Anderson:
i didn't know you could use custom deleters with those types.  i guess that's another thing i'll have to look into.  (thanks!)

Comment: @tecu: That's fine then; I only mentioned it because I don't see them made private in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class looks like a simple wrapper class whose purpose is primarily to wrap a C interface.  In that case I advise you to not complicate your program by using const at all.

I reserve the use of const for clear cut cases where an object or function is read-only.

Const is one of the many C++ features that often trick programmers into making their programs unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: thank you for the tip; i'll have to keep that in mind.  const has certainly caused me enough hangups already.

Comment: One really only needs to make functions const when the class itself is going to be used as a const instance: "const x_link xl;" or "const x_link *xl".  But the only reason to have a const instance of the class is if it is going to be used in a context where its meaningful to say its state cannot be changed.  Thinking about the usage can help one avoid complicated philisophic questions like what constitutes changing the state of a complicated object.